# Prove that $P[ X - E [X] \geq a ] \leq P [ | X - E [X] | \geq a]$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I would like to prove that for any RV $X$ and positive value $a > 0$, it holds that:

$$P[ X - E [X] \geq a ] \leq P [ | X - E [X] | \geq a]$$

Intuitively, I understand that $X - E[X]$ can be negative if the RV $X$ is negative, therefore the probability of being greater than a positive value $a$ is 0, whereas $|X-E[X]|$ is always positive, meaning that the probability of being greater than a positive value $a$ is $\geq 0$. Moreover, in the case that RV $X$ is positive, then both $X-E[X]$ and $|X-E[X]|$ will be the same and then:

$$P[ X - E [X] \geq a ] = P [ | X - E [X] | \geq a]$$

which explains the equal sign in $\leq$ of the inequality.

However, is there a more formal way to prove this inequality?

Comment: The event $\{X-E[X]\geq a\}$ is contained in the event $\{|X-E[X]|\geq a\}$ so this is immediate from P being a probability function

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So, $\{ X - E[X] \geq a \}$ is a subset of $\{ | X - E[X] | \geq a \}$, therefore the probability is less. But I was looking for something more formal.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote for my question?

Comment: If $A \subset B$ then $P(A) \leq P(B)$. That is all you need to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have if $c>0$, $|y|\ge c \iff y \ge c \lor y \le -c$

$$P[|X-E[X]| \ge a]=P[X-E[X] \le -a] + P[X-E[X] \ge a]$$

Hence,

$$P[|X-E[X]| \ge a]\ge P[X-E[X] \ge a]$$

Remark: Even if $X$ is positive, $X-E[X]$ can also take negative value.

Comment: Too complicated an answer. See the comment above by NL 1992.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I have another question, what would happen if $a$ was not necessarily positive?

Comment: If $a \le 0$, the upperbound become $1$ since absolute value is nonnegative, hence the inequality holds trivially.

Comment: Thank you so much!